# Custom post type yearly/ monthly archive permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, redirect, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type "news" in my Wordpress site. I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin to add meta data to each post.

I want to create an array of news items as an archive:

```
[2013]
    [January] => 5
[2012]
    [January] => 20
    [February] => 10
[2011]
    [April] => 30
```

I managed to get this working using:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $news = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT wp_posts.post_date, COUNT(wp_posts.ID) as count
         FROM $wpdb->posts
         WHERE
         wp_posts.post_type = 'news' AND
         wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
         wp_posts.post_date <= CURDATE() AND
         wp_posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
         GROUP BY YEAR(wp_posts.post_date), MONTH(wp_posts.post_date)
         ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC", 
         ARRAY_A);

    $archive = array();
    foreach ($news as $post):
        $year = date('Y', strtotime($post['post_date']));      
        $month = date('m', strtotime($post['post_date']));     
        $month_name = date('F', strtotime($post['post_date']));
        $post['url'] = 'NOT SURE ABOUT URL';
        $archive[$year][$month_name] = $post;
    endforeach;
```

I need to be able to link to specific years and months using `http://example.com/news/2012/` and `http://example.com/news/2012/10/`.

I tried using the plugin [Custom Post Type Archives](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-archives/) but when I goto `/news/2012/` I get the standard news listing with no filter applied.

Here is my Custom Post Type Code

```
register_post_type('news', 
  array(    
    'label' => 'News',
    'description' => 'Latest News',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => '','with_front' => '1'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_position' => 120,
    'menu_icon' => /assets/img/icon-custom.png
  )
);
```

Comment: I assume you're already using the built in `Posts` post type for something else? This is really what posts are set up for - monthly/yearly archives, and will "just work" without having to do anything further. If you want the same behavior for a custom post type, you will unfortunately have to generate your own rewrite rules, which is not so simple.

Comment: Yes, posts is being used for blog posts currently. The news section is a custom post type. Do you have an example of the re-write rules I would need to use for `year` and `month`?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example using [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to handle years and months for a custom post type where `news` is the slug. Visit the `Settings > Permalinks` page in admin to flush rewrite rules after this is added. You could also [put this in a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [flush rewrite rules on plugin activation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules).

```
function wpa83797_news_rewrite_rules(){

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'news/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'news/([0-9]{4})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa83797_news_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo, I've applied the rewrite rules for this but when I access `http://mysite.com/news/2012/` i get redirected to `http://mysite.com/news/`. Can't figure out what the problem is.  I should probably mention that I am using Roots WP framework also. I've had a look through but can't find anything that would be causing this.

Comment: Same happens when I goto: `http://mysite.com/index.php?post_type=news&year=2012&monthnum=10`

Comment: what does your post type registration code look like? try it in twentytwelve to determine if it's theme-related.

Comment: It' seems the issue is to do with the `roots_nice_search_redirect` function in WP Roots. I will amend this function and post the result here. Thank You Milo, your htaccess rules were correct.