# Custom Post Type Yearly Archive Permalinks

Tags: permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

I'm struggling a bit with the permalinks on yearly archives for a custom post type.

I'm using `wp_get_archives` to get a list of the yearly archives but the url for these comes out as follows:

```
http://www.example.localhost/2021/?post_type=reports
```

I would like the urls to match this pattern:

```
http://www.example.localhost/reports/2021/
```

I followed the example in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83803/62753) but the urls are still outputed as in my first example.

```
public function urlRewrites(){
    $slug='reports;
    add_rewrite_rule(
        $slug.'/([0-9]{4})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type='.$slug.'&year=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

I also tried the solution mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/222788/62753). This one changes the urls I get from `wp_get_archives` but they return 404s and has a trailing querystring.

```
http://www.example.localhost/reports/2020/?post_type=reports
```

Example code:

```
public function urlRewritesAgain(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'reports/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
}
```

I am resaving my permalinks each time and I am hooking on to `init`. Am I doing something massively wrong here? Is there a better solution I should be using?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19721/22510

Comment: I hadn't tried that but it doesn't work. It makes no difference to the slug of the main archive.